# Is there a way to pass a parameter into a GraphQL query to specify the GraphQL type it should be run on?

Tags: graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and would like to be able to use a variable for a GraphQL name in a query.

I've attempted to use the standard $ syntax but with no luck.

Working query:

```
query Tryptych($section: SectionsEnum = home) {
  enGB: entries(section: [$section], site: "enGB") {
    ... on Home {
      tryptych {
        ...tryptychFields
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do:

```
query Tryptych($section: SectionsEnum = home, $interface: SomeType = Home) {
  enGB: entries(section: [$section], site: "enGB") {
    ... on $interface {
      tryptych {
        ...tryptychFields
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fragment for reference:

```
fragment tryptychFields on TryptychTryptych {
  __typename
  theme
  tagline
  firstImageTitle
  firstImageContent
  firstImageAsset {
    url
  }
  firstImageLink
  secondImageTitle
  secondImageContent
  secondImageAsset {
    url
  }
  secondImageLink
  thirdImageTitle
  thirdImageContent
  thirdImageAsset {
    url
  }
  thirdImageLink
}
```

In the code snippet for what I'd like to achieve I get the error message:

```
Expected Name, found $
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867966/6124657

Answer (score 0):

A variable can only have one type, that type must be an input type (i.e. a scalar, enum or input object type), and it can only be used where an input type would be expected (i.e. a field or directive argument). In other words, the syntax you're suggesting is not supported.

If you have multiple types that may be returned by the *same field*, you may use any number of fragments to specify the selection set by type. The actual selection set will be determined at runtime when the type of the field is evaluated. For example, if the `animal` field returns a union of `Cat`, `Dog` and `Bird` types:

```
query {
  animal {
    ... on Cat {
      meows
    }
    ... on Dog {
      barks
    }
    ... on Bird {
      chirps
    }
  }
}
```

You may also use the `@skip` and `@include` directives to control which fields are selected:

```
query ($inAHouse: Boolean!, $withAMouse: Boolean!) {
  greenEggs @skip(if: $inAHouse)
  ham @include(if: $withAMouse)
}
```

And you may include multiple operations in a single document, and then specify an `operationName` with your request to tell the server which operation to run:

```
query OperationA {
  foo
}

query OperationB {
  bar
}
```